# Using contextlib.suppress in place of nested try/else with return statement inside function

Tags: python, try-catch, suppress, error-suppression

I am attempting to abide by flake8 guidelines by using `contextlib.suppress` in place of a nested try/else within a function that returns a variable.  Below is my original function:

```
def _get_early_stopping_rounds(model, **kwargs) -> int:
    """Returns the number of early stopping rounds."""
    try:
        n_rounds = kwargs["early_stopping_rounds"]
    except Exception:
        try:
            n_rounds = model.get_params()["early_stopping_rounds"]
        except Exception:
            try:
                n_rounds = None
            except Exception:
                pass

    return n_rounds
```

Example usage:

```
from xgboost import XGBClassifier

# Define xgb model object
>>> xgb = XGBClassifier(early_stopping_rounds=20)
>>> _get_early_stopping_rounds(xgb)
20
```

Replacing nested try/else with contextlib.suppress:

```
from contextlib import suppress

def _get_early_stopping_rounds(model, **kwargs) -> int:
    """Returns the number of early stopping rounds."""
    with suppress(Exception):
        n_rounds = kwargs["early_stopping_rounds"]
        with suppress(Exception):
            n_rounds = model.get_params()["early_stopping_rounds"]
            with suppress(Exception):
                n_rounds = None
    return n_rounds
```

Example usage:

```
>>> _get_early_stopping_rounds(xgb)
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'n_rounds' referenced before assignment
```

I'm not sure that I understand the UnboundLocalError I am receiving.  What is the proper approach for using `contextlib.suppress` inside of a function that returns a variable?

Answer (score 0):

Old question, but I think it's worth answering.

You're receiving an UnboundLocalError because you are trying to use `n_rounds` when it was never defined. It was never defined because the line where it was defined caused an exception. The exception was suppressed, but the line that caused it wasn't executed (because it couldn't: it ran into an exception), so the variable that was assigned there was not assigned in the end.

There are two possible solutions:

## Either don't use `suppress()`:

You can simply use a normal `try/except` and define what should happen if an exception occurred:

```py
try:
  my_assignment = something["some_key"]
except KeyError:
  my_assignment = "some fallback value"
```

Then `my_assignment` will always be defined.

## Or assign a value ahead of time

```py
my_assignment = None

with contextlib.suppress(KeyError):
  my_assignment = something["some_key"]
```

Then `my_assignment` will always exist at least with a value of `None`, even if the assignment to `something["some_key"]` fails.

This option might make type checkers and linters unhappy because they'll see a variable being assigned to twice without being used in the middle. I think that's their issue, since they don't consider the case that the line may be skipped, causing the variable to never be assigned.

Comment: Those are also the answers I came up with and they're both not very Pythonic/satisfactory unfortunately. Wish it would be more like Rust handles exceptions via Ok()

Comment: So they're not pythonic because they're not what Rust does? Use the conventions of the language you're working with. Both those solutions are fine and readable. The try/except one at the very least is always acceptable.